# Alfresco: Web scripts url mapping behaves differently when written in Java vs. Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, alfresco, web-scripting, alfresco-webscripts

I had come across a problem with web scripts and their URL patterns and behavior in Alfresco, depending whether the web script is written in Java or JavaScript. Since it took me some time to figure it out, I want to share it here.

Original post in the Alfresco forum:
https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/web-scripts/webscripts-url-mapping-behaves-differently-when-written-java

---

I just noticed some behavior regarding web scripts. Maybe somebody has an idea why this happens or whether it's a bug in Alfresco.

I have two (GET) web scripts:

**Webscript A** has the following URL in it's descriptor:

```
<url>/api/v1/folders/{path}</url>
```

**Webscript B** has the following URL in it's descriptor:

```
<url>/api/v1/folders/{path}/files</url>
```

Note that the urls only differ with the "`/files`" in the end.

The strange thing now is that when both web scripts are written in javascript (thus also not needed to be registered in any xml context file), it's not possible to reach webscript B, because A already caught the requests falsely (because of the overlapping URL pattern, I assume, but without checking for further patterns that match better).
For example, I call the URL like:

```
GET /api/v1/folders/myFolderX/files
```

**I would expect that the request would go to webscript B (due to the "/files" at the end), but instead it goes to webscript A, which throws an error due to mismatching business logic in there of course.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**: **I rewrote the web scripts in Java** (and no changes to the descriptor or url pattern), register them in my xml context file, then everything works as expected and my request actually reaches webscript B.

Comment: I would call it a work around - not a solution. Could you please raise a bug in jira for that since it is still a bug in the js implementation?

Comment: Thanks for raising this.
Issue has been moved for investigation: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-14496